# Cannot connect iOS device to my MongoDb database on my mac using ObjCMongoDb

Tags: ios, macos, mongodb, localhost, objcmongodb

So I have everything set up like it says to do on GitHub, but for some reason I can't connect to MongoDb on the local server. I have the IP set to 127.0.0.1, with the correct collection name. Is there another step that's not in the documentation that I'm missing here?

Comment: Can you post some code so people can help you

Comment: You're connecting your iOS device to a MongoDB located on your Mac and you used the IP address `127.0.0.1`? You'll need the port opened for MongoDB (27017) and the IP address of your Mac.

Comment: Yep...your right.  Stupid oversight on my part.  I needed to use the ip address of my mac.  That fixed it.  Thanks.